# No releases available for package

Tags: php, pear, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install some pear packages such as gnupg in a Ubuntu OS in virtualbox, but if i use `sudo pecl install gnupg`, it throws

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/gnupg"
install failed
```

It is not only happening for gnupg, but for all pear packages. But i couldn't identify what exactly the issue is. The same command is working in my another virtual machine. So i'm really confused. Please help.

**Note:**

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
Running on: Linux udhay-dev 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64
```

This is what the pear configuration (using `pear config-show`) shows,

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       http://foo.bar/
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /home/udhay-dev/pear/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /home/udhay-dev/pear/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /home/udhay-dev/pear/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /home/udhay-dev/pear/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /home/udhay-dev/pear/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /home/udhay-dev/pear/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /home/udhay-dev/pear/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            2
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /etc/pear/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /home/udhay-dev/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear/pear.conf
```

When i use `pear clear-cache`, it shows,

Directory /tmp/pear/cache not found.

For the commands `pear update-channels` and `pear upgrade`, i got,

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/http.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/http.so: undefined symbol: php_persistent_handle_abandon in Unknown on line 0
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message: Connection to `foo.bar:8080' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Trying channel "doc.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "doc.php.net" (Connection to `foo.bar:8080' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message: Connection to `foo.bar:8080' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Trying channel "pear.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.php.net" (Connection to `foo.bar:8080' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message: Connection to `foo.bar:8080' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Trying channel "pecl.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pecl.php.net" (Connection to `foo.bar:8080' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
```

Comment: for clear-cache. try creating the directory then see what happens. for http.so try `grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -i "extension="` and look for any stray php.ini files. then `sudo aptitude purge http` and `sudo aptitude install http` if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried entering this before?

```
pear clear-cache
pear update-channels
pear upgrade
```

Comment: This worked for me.  After an original failed install, I got the no releases available error.  Had to do this on the second attempt.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem with pecl and oci8. Resolved by setting the proxy to get through our firewall:

```
sudo pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@proxy.domain:port
```

Perhaps this is your problem?

Comment: RUN pear config-set http_proxy  ... work for me

Answer (score 3):

It seems that any connection problem can cause `pear install` to return "no releases available". Other pear commands like `pear list-upgrades` and `pear update-channels` return more useful errors.

When the OP ran `pear update-channels` they got "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" errors. So my guess would be that the OP had some kind of DNS configuration problem on their VM.

In our own case our Linux server was an AWS EC2 instance. When we ran `pear list-upgrades` we saw "Connection timed out" messages. So our problem was that our AWS security group was blocking outbound HTTP traffic.

Comment: Great hint, my problem was the following error: `Connection to `ssl://pear.php.net:443' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?` After enabling extension `openssl`, things worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing `ev` and `clear-cache` did not work!

In my case, the problem was solved by reinstalling the `php-pear`.

So, I tried `sudo apt remove php-pear` and then `sudo apt-get install php-pear`

Answer (score -1):

In my case I used `pecl` binary instead of `pear` binary and it helped to install package and get rid of `No releases available...` error.

I know that OP used `pecl` but I came here after having the exact same error in chef using `php_pear` resource so I'll leave it here in case someone will find this page like I did.